# How can I insert multiple children along with parent record using Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to create a simple shopping application using Laravel, I am using [LaravelShoppingCart](https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart) plugin to store items in the user session. When the user hits my `store` method the `order` and `order_line` records should be stored.

I am currently getting this error with the code below:

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::__construct()
>   must be of the type array, object given, called in
>   /home/vagrant/site/app/Http/Controllers/BasketController.php on line
>   130 and defined

**Table schema:**

```
// create orders table
Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->text('order_notes')->nullable();
    $table->decimal('subtotal', 5, 2)->default(0);
    $table->timestamps();
});

// create order lines table
Schema::create('order_lines', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('order_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('order_id')->references('id')->on('orders')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->integer('menu_item_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('menu_item_id')->references('id')->on('menu_item');
    $table->decimal('sale_price', 5, 2);
    $table->integer('quantity');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Order Model (relationship):**

```
/**
 * Define relationship to OrderLines
 * @return [type] [description]
 */
public function order_line()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\OrderLine');
}
```

**OrderLine Model (relationship):**

```
public function order()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Order');
}
```

**Store Function:**

```
public function store(CreateOrderGuestRequest $request)
{

    $order = new Order;

    $order->order_notes = $request->order_notes;
    $order->save();

    $order_lines = new Collection();

    foreach (Cart::content() as $row) {
        $order_lines->push([
            'menu_item_id' => $row->id,
            'quanity'      => $row->qty,
            'sale_price'   => $row->price
        ]);
    }

    $order->order_line()->saveMany(new OrderLine($order_lines));

    // redirect somewhere after


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were pretty close. You just need to make a few adjustments to get this to work. You need to pass a collection of models or an array of models to the [`saveMany`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#inserting-related-models) method so when you loop through, instead of "pushing" an array, "push" a new OrderLine model like this:

```
foreach (Cart::content() as $row) {
    $order_lines->push(
        new OrderLine([
            'menu_item_id' => $row->id,
            'quanity'      => $row->qty,
            'sale_price'   => $row->price
        ])
    );
}
```

Then, when you call `saveMany`, just pass the `$order_lines` collection;

```
$order->order_line()->saveMany($order_lines);
```

This, of course, is assuming `Cart::content()` is valid.

On a related note: `saveMany` will not insert all the entries with a single query. It'll loop through and add them one-by-one. To do a bulk insert with just a single query, you need to use the query builder.

Edit: An example of how to use the [`insert`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#inserts) method using the query builder:

```
$order_lines = [];

foreach (Cart::content() as $row) {
    $order_lines[] = [
        'menu_item_id' => $row->id,
        'quanity'      => $row->qty,
        'sale_price'   => $row->price,
        'order_id'     => $order->id
    ];
}

DB::table('order_lines')->insert($order_lines);
```

You just build an array of data to insert into the table and insert it.