# Add an array of ids to other table in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have two tables stories and featured Story so I want to add the few story ids to featured table in a single request. How to do that?

here is my code to add the single id to featured story table.

```
public function saveFeatured($id)
    {
        # code...
        $story = $this->getById($id);
        $storyId = $story->id;
        $featured = new FeaturedStory();
        $featured->story_id = $storyId;
        $featured->save();
        return "Added to featured StoryList";
    }
```

Comment: why not write an insert query? or something like `DB::table('featuredstory')->insert([['story_id' => $id1], ['story_id' => $id2] ]);` or raw query

Comment: how are you planning on passing these few story ids? via request input?

Comment: yes request input

Answer (score 1):

Pass an array of id to the function and then do like this.

```
public function saveFeatured($arrayid){
    foreach($arrayid as $key => $item){
        $story = $this->getById($item);
        $storyId = $story->id;
        $featured = new FeaturedStory();
        $featured->story_id = $storyId;
        $featured->save();    
    }
    return "Added to featured StoryList";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: [has-many-create-relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method)

In your Story.php model:

```php
public function featuredStories()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\FeaturedStory::class, 'story_id', 'id');
}
```

In your FeaturedStory.php model:

```php
public function story()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Story::class);
}
```

And then you can create `featured_stories` easily;

```php
$array = ... # your featured_stories attributes array.
$story->featuredStories()->createMany($array);
```

This will automatically fill the `story_id` in `FeaturedStory`

Comment: Do you mean  ->createMany() ? @TsaiKoga

Comment: @John Sorry, my mistake. I have fixed the syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [saveMany](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method)() or [createMany](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method)() methods.
First, fill an array by several items, then store them at one eloquent call. Also @Cerlin methioned raw insert method in the comment to the question.

I don't know how you get input and what the meaning of "featured" exactly, but it can look like:

```php
$story->featured()->saveMany([
    new App\Featured(['id' => 1, 'title' => 'First story']),
    new App\Featured(['id' => 2, 'title' => 'Another story']),
]);
```

It was very similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33769331/272885

Comment: Hey input will be from postman as request and in controller $story = $request->all();

Comment: but i am facing a problem now is its tasking the last value only when i try to send more than 1 ids in postman x-www-form

Comment: @John how are you naming the input and what are you assigning